# 3 is Square in finite field

Tags: finite-fields, quadratic-reciprocity

Let $K$ be a finite field with $p^2$ elements. Show that $3$ is square in $K$.

I know that 3 is sum of two squares.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Observe that the splitting field of the polynomial $x^2-3$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is either $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, so that either way, the square roots of $3$ lie in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$.